# how to check empty url coming in xslt

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, dataviewwebpart

I have a list in sharepoint 2013 having columns as Url(type:URL),Title(Note).I want to display
Url in case it is present and if not then i want to display the Title in DataViewWebPart.So i want to check this condition in xslt.

Comment: Could you actually show the XSLT you are currently using? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried XSL:IF:
`<xsl:if test="@URL = ''"><div>I'm blank</div></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="@URL != ''"><div>I'm not blank</div></xsl:if>`